# Aligning message-bubbles right and left

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is align each of the message bubbles to one side, so first one goes on the left side and second one on the right. The problem currently as you may see in the fiddle is that if the message is too short it is displayed on the same row.

Please expand the "Result" window in order to see the problem on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ry86dzz/)

Here's the code also:

HTML:

```
<section id="chat-box" class="clearfix">
    <ul class="messages clearfix">
        <li>hefajgf jajgahg jahgjahgjahgj ahgjahgjaghajhg</li>
        <li>hefajgfagkjhajhgajhgajsghjasghajagkjagjka eieajgieagjaeigjaei jeagi</span></li>
        <li>hello</li>
        <li>hello</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #e6e7e9;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.clearfix:after { 
  content: "."; 
  display: block; 
  height: 0; 
  clear: both; 
  visibility: hidden; 
}
.clearfix { 
  display: inline-block;  
}
* html .clearfix {  
  height: 1%;  
} 
.clearfix {  
  display: block;  
}
section#chat-box {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    height: ;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 600px
}

ul.messages {
    padding: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul.messages li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    min-width: 250px;
    background: #a6acba;
    border: 4px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

ul.messages li:after, ul.messages li:before {
    right: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

ul.messages li:after {
    border-color: rgba(166, 172, 186, 0);
    border-right-color: #a6acba;
    border-width: 12px;
    margin-top: -16px;
}
ul.messages li:before {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right-color: transparent;
    border-width: 26px;
    margin-top: -26px;
}

ul.messages li:nth-child(2n) {
    background: #76a0be;
    float: right;
}

ul.messages li:nth-child(2n):after, ul.messages li:nth-child(2n):before {
    border-right-color: transparent;
    left: 100%;
}

ul.messages li:nth-child(2n):after {
    border-left-color: #76a0be;
}
ul.messages li:nth-child(2n):before {
    border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing to `clear` the `li` elements on both sides.

Try adding this CSS rule:

```
li{
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

You could place these rules on more appropriate place, I did it like this just to show you what are you missing.

See it in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1ry86dzz/2/)